# Is full table scan needed for counting rows with some attribute bigger than x?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-performance

Let's say there a table of people, with an `age` column which is indexed. How fast would be a query to count people older than 20: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people WHERE age > 20`? Is full table scan required? The database is MySQL.

Comment: Run an explain, and see what happens?

Comment: Let's see the exact index.  Is that the exact query?  Which engine?  Is all the data/index cached in RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the column age is not indexed, then yes, a full table scan is required.
Even if it is indexed, if the data distribution of age values is such that there are more than a certain threshold percentage of the records that have age > 20, then a table scan is required anyway.  it works this way, for each row that would be returned by the query, the processor must execute n disk IO operations, where n is the number of levels in the index... If there are, say a million rows in the table, and the index on age is 5 levels deep, then if there are more than 200k rows with age value > 20 then for each of those rows the processor has to execute 5 I/Os, for a total of 200k * 5 = 1 million I/Os, so, the optimizer says, if my statistics indicate that more than 200k rows would be returned, I might as well do a complete table scan, that will require less than 1 Million I/Os.

The only exception to this is if the entire table is *clustered* on the age column, then you only need to traverse the index for the *boundaries* of the age range you want to filter on.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in the Accepted Answer.  Rather than dissect that Answer, I will start fresh:

Given `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people WHERE age > 20`, here is the performance for InnoDB, fastest first:

```
1. `INDEX(age)`            -- Range scan within the index
2. `INDEX(age, ...)`       -- Range scan within the index
3. `INDEX(foo, age)`       -- Full Index scan
4. `PRIMARY KEY(age, ...)` -- Range scan within the table
5. No indexes              -- Table scan needed
6. `PRIMARY KEY(foo, ...)  -- Table scan needed (same as "No index")
```

Notes and caveats:

- `INDEX(age, ...)` is a littler slower than `INDEX(age)` only because the index is bulkier.
- Any secondary index containing all the columns mentioned anywhere in the `SELECT` (just `age`, in this example) is called a "covering" index.  `EXPLAIN` will say `Using index` (not to be confused with `Using index condition`).  A covering index is faster than other secondary indexes.  (If we had another column in the select, I could say more.)
- Note "Range scan" vs "scan" -- This is where the processing can drill down the BTree index (primary or secondary) to where `age = 20` and scan forward.  That is, it does not need to scan the entire table or index, hence Range scan" is faster than "scan".
- Items 3 and 4 may not be in the correct order.  Item 3 may be faster when the index is significantly less bulky than the table.  Item 4 may be faster when the range is a small fraction of the table.  Because of this "maybe", I can't say "a covering index is always faster than using the `PRIMARY KEY`".  Instead I can only say "usually faster".
- A million rows is likely to have only 3 levels of BTree.  However this part of the computation is almost never worth pursuing.  (Rule of Thumb:  each level of an index or table BTree fans out by a factor of 100.)
- If the necessary part of the data or index is not already cached in RAM, then there will be I/O -- this can drastically slow down any of the cases.  It can even turn the fastest case into slower than all the rest.
- If the the data/index is too big to be cached, then there will always be I/O.  In this case the ordering will stay roughly the same, but the differences will be more pronounced.  (For example, "bulkier" becomes a significant factor.)
- `SELECT name FROM t WHERE age>20` is a different can of worms.  Some of what I have said does *not* carry over to it.  (Ask another Question if you want me to spell that out.  It will have more cases.)
- MyISAM and MEMORY have differences relative to InnoDB.